# How to Modify Data as Inserted

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, database-trigger

I am trying to solve a data ingestion problem.

There is an application that collects some data and spits it into our database, but the problem is the date it is collecting has been modified on the client side to be like 'DDD DDMMMYYYY':

```
'Sat 20May2017'
```

The application is not ours, and we have no access to its source code. I want to simply drop the 'DDD' part from the date prior to its insert, but I have been unable to successfully accomplish this.

The table column is defined as:

```
SOURCE_DATE DATE NOT NULL
```

As is, the inserts fail with:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

But they *will* work with the format 'DDMMMYYYY' (I have tested this).

I tried creating a trigger to solve the issue, but nothing I have tried has worked. Most recent attempt:

```
CREATE TRIGGER T_FORMAT_DATE
ON MY_TABLE
INSTEAD OF INSERT AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(SOURCE_DATE)
   SELECT RIGHT(SOURCE_DATE, LEN(SOURCE_DATE) - 4)
   FROM inserted;
END
```

Side question: is there a way to know when/if a trigger has executed?

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not feel like this is the *best* answer, but here is *a* way:

I created a "go-between" table that sets the **SOURCE_DATE** field to **VARCHAR(13)**.

Then, my trigger or @Yogesh or @rahul triggers will work just fine. The issue is the table constraints are checked *at insert* and *prior to the execution of the trigger*.

Comment: if the below answers useful, then accept or vote up the solution/answer.

Comment: I was hoping someone was going to respond with a better answer. I feel like mine is just a workaround, not a true solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the week day like sat, sun, mon, etc.. from your desired date string then below short command will help you.

```
DECLARE @DATE NVARCHAR(80);

SET @DATE = 'Sat 20May2017'

select LTRIM(REPLACE(@DATE, SUBSTRING(@DATE, 1, 3), '')) DATE
```

Output :

```
+===========+
| DATE      |
+===========+
| 20May2017 |
+-----------+
```

Comment: Its still returning a string, convert that to date

Comment: i have given the answer as per "But they will work with the format 'DDMMMYYYY' (I have tested this)."

Comment: @Sobmac no issue, string date would be insert in table i have tested.

Comment: I have tried both this solution and yours (@rahul), but I can get neither to work as a trigger. TBC, I have tested, and they both, of course, work inline with an INSERT.  I have been searching online in the meantime, and as best I can tell, the issue is that MSSQL has no real concept of BEFORE (like Oracle). Meaning, though I am intending to fix the data prior to the insert, the inserted data is checked against the table constraints and throws the error prior to the trigger firing.  If either of you actually got this to work as a trigger, I would be interested in knowing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the week day like sat, sun, mon, etc.. you can use **try_parse** `function`

```
DECLARE @DATE NVARCHAR(80);
SET @DATE = 'Sat 20May2017';
SELECT Replace(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), TRY_PARSE(@DATE AS DATE), 106), ' ', '');
```